# Convert org table to MS Excel?

Tags: org-table

Windows 10, Emacs 26.1

I has org mode table. Is it possible to convert it to MS Excel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I have two suggestions, depending on your system and requirements. Assuming you have cygwin installed then (1) should be possible - otherwise, try (2).

(1) Use ssconvert. This is a linux command line utility to convert spreadsheet files between various spreadsheet file formats. It is a companion utility to  Gnumeric. Add something like this to you emacs init:

```
    (add-to-list 'org-odt-convert-processes
               '("gnumeric" "/usr/bin/ssconvert %i %o"))
```

You should then be able to convert to ms-excel.

2. Use this defun:

   ```
    (defun org-table-export-to-spreadsheet (arg)
     "Export org table to spreadsheet formats, e.g. `ods', `xls', `xlsx'."
      (interactive "sFormat: ")
      (let* ((source-file  (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name  (current-buffer))))
      (csv-file (concat source-file ".csv")))
      (org-table-export csv-file "orgtbl-to-csv")
      (org-odt-convert csv-file arg)))
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I export to HTML and open the HTML, the I copy the table from there and paste to excel.

Comment: Also works with Libreoffice Calc.

Answer (score 0):

For future references, the answer that @user16762 wrote works but it has a little typo. Instead of "current- buffer" it should be "current-buffer".

This is the fixed version:

```
(defun org-table-export-to-spreadsheet (arg)
 "Export org table to spreadsheet formats, e.g. `ods', `xls', `xlsx'."
  (interactive "sFormat: ")
  (let* ((source-file  (file-name-sans-extension (buffer-file-name  (current-buffer))))
  (csv-file (concat source-file ".csv")))
  (org-table-export csv-file "orgtbl-to-csv")
  (org-odt-convert csv-file arg)))
```

Comment: I edited the other answer to fix the typo. Maybe the OP can can accept it now to close the loop?